# how to get NeighboringCell Information(related to network info) in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have to grapple to find  neighbourCell information using the blackberry api package "net.rim.device.api.system" . The same is directly available in android at the link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html.

can anybody suggest me some alternative to workaround ?

Thanks

Comment: Not available within the BlackBerry API, at least I've never found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your network cell information via these methods:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo;
```

Cell ID -> `GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId()`

Location Area Code -> `GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC()`

Comment: According to the BlackBerry API documentation getCellID() returns the current cell ID. getLAC() returns the Location Area Code. The OP is looking for neighbouring cell information.

Comment: @Ahmet I want to find the neighbour cell information, not the current cell information.

Comment: sorry i misunderstand the question